# Druid.io (imply): log level settings

Tags: logging, log4j, druid, bigdata

During druid.io work I found out that log files which located in `/druid_dir/var/sv/` takes gigabytes of space.

To fix this problem I want to set log level to `ERROR`

I put in **common.runtime.properties**

```
druid.emitter.logging.logLevel=error
```

and in **log4j2.xml**:

```
Configuration status="ERROR"
```

but **.log** files still grow to huge sizes (and includes INFO messages).

What else should be added to the config?

Answer (score 1):

Need to update root logger level in log4j2.xml:

```
<Root level="error">
```

Comment: Is the settings in the question still necessary with this config?